# Beveled 3d text in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there any way to create beveled 3d text in Unity3D 5, without getting 3Ds max/maya involved?

[image]

Comment: for the gui or for the play mode?

Comment: Play mode, the 3D texts is for a AR project.

Comment: mhh... not exact letters  but you can use "Probuilder"  https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/11919 which is great tool,you'll be able to create letter shapes  and other stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an empty GameObject, then select it, and go Component> Mesh> Text Mesh.
Make the font as big as you want it, but it won't be how you wanted it in your picture. Although you can still change font, color, rotation and position.

You could also try [3D Text](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/693) on the Asset Store. Unfortunately that has not been updated since 2011, so I don't really recommend it. The reviews don't really help either. I recommend that you read them.

So I think that using Blender, Maya, 3ds Max, or something along those lines would be your best and probably only answer.

Here is a video that I found on YouTube, showing how to use Blender to make 3D text: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=85_U7fVWtH0

From Flo.
I hope it helps.

Edit: As DoughnutZombie stated, you could use ProBuilder, but I don't think it would be too simple to make a word out of it.